# image data type SQL Server 2008 C# data type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a data table

```
CREATE TABLE [ProductImages]
(
[ProductImageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductImage] [image] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductImages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 (
   [ProductImageID] ASC
 ) 
)
```

I'm trying to write ProductImages class in C#

```
public class ProductImages
{
    private int productImageID;

    public int ProductImageID
    {
        get { return productImageID; }
        set { productImageID = value; }
    }

 // I need to declare property for ProductImage???

}
```

How do i declare property for ProductImage ?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, `IMAGE` is **deprecated** - you shouldn't be using it anymore. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead

Comment: You may cast IMAGE to VARBINARY(MAX) by using CAST(MyImageField AS VARBINARY(MAX). In turn, you may cast VARBINARY(MAX) to VARCHAR(MAX) if needed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
public byte[] ProductImage { get; set;}
```

Would work...  Images are just binary files and you marshal them between SQL Server and your application as the byte[] data type.

Answer (score 12):

Use a `byte[]` in c# and I suggest changing your column type to `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Support for the image data type will be [removed in the future](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191262.aspx).

Comment: Okay, +1 for mentioning varbinary(max).  I missed that the first time I saw this.  It's a MUCH better way of storing the data.  Incidentally, it's pretty easy to convert that over to using FILESTREAMs as well, which is the preferred way of dealing with files being uploaded to SQL.