# Values from Image column are different than expected after insertion

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm developing a windows form application for insert records contained in a table from one database from another table located in a different database.

The involved column is called `FPTemplate` and its data type is `Image`.

Using this line of code for get the information of a column which its data type is `System.Byte[]`  *(in the DataTable variable)*:

```
BitConverter.ToString((byte[])row["FPTemplate"], 0)
```

I don't get the expected results *which I detailed in the following lines*.

When I make the insert with this code-behind<sup>1</sup>:

```
// Insert records in "UserFinger" destination table.
string sql_cmd = "";
DataTable dt; // Has the info obtained from origin database.

// Loop rows of 'dt' variable.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // Build the T-SQL statement to execute.
    sql_cmd = " INSERT INTO UserFinger (Userid, Fingerid, FPTemplate) " +
              " VALUES ('" + row["Userid"].ToString() + "', " + row["Fingerid"].ToString() + ", '" + BitConverter.ToString((byte[])row["FPTemplate"], 0) + "')";

    // Execute built T-SQL statement.
    ExecuteSQL(GetConnectionStringSQL_Cloud(), "UserFinger", sql_cmd);
}
```

I get this results in the *destination* table - *see `FPTemplate` column* -:

[image: Results in destination table]

But, in the *origin* table, its values - *in the `FPTemplate` column* - are:

[image: Results in origin table]

How can I correctly send the *origin* values to the *destination* table?

I think this is due to use `BitConverter` instead of `ByteConverter`, but I have no idea how to proceed for get the desired results, honestly.

---

<sup>1</sup> I know this isn't the best way to do the insertions of the records, this is a test I'm working.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting problems.  Even for your "test".  What field type is FPTemplate in the database?

Comment: @LarsTech field FPTemplate is `Image` type. I edited my question.

Comment: The image datatype has been deprecated for more than a decade now in favor of varbinary(max).

Comment: @SeanLange I didn't know until you mention it, thank you. Unfortunately, this is for a control access system that is already in the market, so I don't think it is possible for change its data type. Sorry for bother you, but, do yo have any idea about my question? I mean, how to solve this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285757/image-data-type-sql-server-2008-c-sharp-data-type - you might have to create a view with a cast